# In a Windows PE file, what happens when 2 sections have the same raw address?

Tags: reverse-engineering, portable-executable

I'm taking a look at a PE executable packed with UPX and the sections are laid out as follows:

UPX0: raw addr: **0x400**, raw size: *0x0*,   virtual addr: 0x1000, virtual size: 0x6000

UPX1: raw addr: **0x400**, raw size: 0xC00, virtual addr: 0x7000, virtual size: 0x1000

Section UPX0 has a raw size of zero and has the same raw address as UPX1. My question is, what data goes into section UPX0 when the PE executable is loaded into memory?

Based on other information I've read, the Windows loader pads a section with 0's when the virtual size is greater than the raw size of a section. Since the raw size of UPX0 is 0, does that mean that the entire section is initially filled with 0's when the executable is loaded? Or are virtual addresses 0x1000 - 0x1C00 (UPX0) filled with the same data as virtual addresses 0x7000 - 0x7C00 (UPX1) and addresses 0x1C01 - 0x6FFF (UPX0) padded with 0's? Or does something else happen?

Comment: your first assumption is right, the UPX0 section will in memory be initialized with all zero.

Comment: @0xC0000022L -- post that as an answer and I'll give you an upvote for it :)

Comment: Ok, so it looks like the PE-Bliss PE library is correctly handling the virtual data for UPX0 (0x6000 bytes of 0's). I was confused about this since objdump gives the 'copy of the raw data in UPX1' result rather than the 0 padding result (and IDA-Pro lists the contents of UPX0 as '??' to ensure that I don't know the answer).

Answer (score 0):

Source: @0xC0000022L

> Your first assumption is right, the UPX0 section will in memory be initialized with all zero.

And, because the **UPX0** raw size is 0x0, then it will be filled with 0x0 when loading and **UPX1** will have the data located in that location.